# How to populate Azure Active Directory B2C user custom user attributes?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I've been successfully using curl to fetch and update the postal code of a user in my Azure Active Directory Tenant with commands like this:

```
curl -X GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userGuid>?\$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode,xyz -H "Authorization: Bearer $AAD_BEARER_TOKEN"
```

This displays the displayName, givenName and postalCode but ignores the custom string attribute xyz that I created using the web browser UI at portal.azure.com.

Note that since I'm using cygwin bash on windows, I have to escape my dollars and ampersands.

How can I use curl to populate this new field I created called xyz?

I've tried [using open extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users) but the samples don't work (possibly because they don't include a bearer token and they don't specify a specific user). Can I expect to see the custom attribute "xyz" I created with the Web UI on portal.azure.com show up?

```
curl -X GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?\$select=id,displayName,mail,mobilePhone\&\$expand=extensions
```

This gives me "InvalidAuthenticationToken". When I add a bearer token I get

```
Resource '1acbf9cc-d931-4ff3-bafe-218693fba30e' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

**Tue March 02 2021 evening update:**

Shame on me! I forgot the most important question: how do I post/patch a new value so I have something to fetch (GET)? I cannot tell if the GET is working because the value is empty.

**Wed March 03 2021 morning update:**
I finally found [the docs on custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and it says I need to modify my custom policy in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml. Stanley: did you do this? I'm not clear on the XML for InputClaims, PersistClaims & OutputClaims. Do I need to edit this XML and upload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, you want to get the custom attribute value of a user by Microsoft Graph API.

If so, the attribute `xyz` in `$select` param should be:`extension_<your B2C application ID remove all '-' characters>_xyz`

On my side, I can find my B2C application ID here:
[image]

And I have a custom attribute `id4GTM`:
[image]

If I want to get its value of a user,the attribute name should be: `extension_48c33b45c4f8419eb9d97a0f3ff1817b_id4GTM`, the request URL should be :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/8bbd6746-02c7-41a6-97ca-c745c8d27a23?$select=displayname,extension_48c33b45c4f8419eb9d97a0f3ff1817b_id4GTM
```

Result:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

If you want to set a B2C custom attribute for a user by Micorsoft Graph API, just try the request below:

request URL:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user guid>
```

Request Body:

```
{"extension_d98794e6f3ca42a6b755d6f9cca552e1_xyz": "<value you want to set>"}
```

On my side just as below:
[image]

Try to get this value:
[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions :)

Comment: Thanks Stan! Here is my attempt:
 

    curl -X GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userguid>?\$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode,extension_d98794e6f3ca42a6b755d6f9cca552e1_xyz -H "Authorization: Bearer $AAD_BEARER_TOKEN"
    

 
 
 
 
 
 
 {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,givenName,postalCode,extension_d98794e6f3ca42a6b755d6f9cca552e1_xyz)/$entity","displayName":"Uncle Ben","givenName":"Ben","postalCode":"11073"}

Maybe I need to set a value first? Please see my update.

Comment: @user3477493, if you just want to set/get your B2C user custom attribute by Microsoft graph API, there is no need to use B2C custom policy. And Yes, you need to set it first, otherwise, this value will not be returned. I have updated my answer about how to use Microsoft Graph API to set a custom attribute value for a user

Comment: Shucks! I did not look at your screen shot closely enough! Shame on me again! You have to use that special app registration (that you highlighted) that does not appear in the list of registrations by default. Your patch example works too! It is a shame that the Microsoft documentation does not include an example of patching a new value. (Since using the wrong AppId worked for fetching the standard attributes I assumed I had the write AppID). I hope this will help someone else too! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3477493 Glad to know it helps :)